# In modern Jewish Passover meals, is the wine mixed with water?

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada

The reason why I am curious about this is because every Christian church (except the Orthodox Armenians) adds water to the wine in the Eucharistic chalice before consecration. They also claim that Jesus did this because it had become a part of the Passover meal in his time.

For example, the Catholics claim:

> In the ancient world, the Greeks added water to wine because it was often thick, gritty, and too strong. It was simply good taste to add water to wine before drinking it. The Romans loved all things Greek, so they adopted Greek manners and spread them to the lands they conquered. **And even though it was not originally a Jewish custom to add water to wine, it soon became part of the Passover meal itself and, hence, part of our Mass.**

https://www.uscatholic.org/church/scripture-and-theology/2011/10/why-does-priest-pour-water-wine-and-put-piece-bread-cup

Is there any truth to the last sentence? I just want to fact check this.

Comment: https://seforimblog.com/2012/11/wine-strength-and-dilution/

Comment: @Double AA: Thanks for the link, but I was looking for an answer more specific to the wine at the Passover meal - whereas your link seems to be more about how it was more common historically for Jews to drink diluted wine in general than it is now.

Comment: @7Mess if you read the entire article you will see that Jews once did this at every meal and no longer do so at all. Cheers.

Comment: @Josh K: Thanks for the explanation - so it was only a practical necessity once upon a time but never a matter of religious law. I guess that explains it. I'll wait and see if anyone else has more information to contribute on this subject.

Comment: See [*P'sachim* 108b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=108b&format=text) ("א"ר יהודה אמר שמואל ארבעה כוסות הללו צריך שיהא בהן כדי מזיגת כוס יפה שתאן חי יצא... אמר רבא ידי יין יצא ידי חירות לא יצא") and commentaries ad loc.

Comment: To VTCers: Comparative religion is not the same as comparative religion-based.

Comment: @DoubleAA- great little article(!), all sorts of background and relevant info there.

Comment: I seem to remember this subject being discussed in detail in the Pesach guides of Rabbi Avraham Blumenkrantz z”l. I recall him making a comment about all commercial wine in the 1 litre or 1.75 litre bottles being diluted with water as part of the kosher supervision process adopted by all major labels today. Bli neder, I’ll see if I can find one of his old guides which discusses this.

Comment: After checking a few of Rabbi Blumenkrantz’s Pesach guides (1996-2002) he started by only discussing how much one can dilute pure wine with water & still be permissible for the 4 cups. But by 2002 he stated many commercial producers add water and that in his opinion, if added prior to fermentation is not considered adding water according halacha. He also noted the kabbalistic practice of some to add water at the seder table even for seder & commented that as little as 3 drops of water fulfills this practice.

Comment: The reason most historical Christian churches usually add water to the communion wine is because the latter signifies the blood shed on Golgotha, which, according to the Gospel of John (19:34), was mixed with water.